# How to get Dlookup to return and display a hyperlink in Access 2010/2013

Tags: ms-access, hyperlink, vba

How do I get a Dlookup to return a hyperlink from a table field set as hyperlink, and display the hyperlink in a textbox? The textbox only returns name I have given for the string as the hyperlink and not the actual hyperlink that is in the table field. When I click on what is displayed in the textbox, it can't find the path since the hyperlink is only the string name. Am I supposed to format the Dlookup differently? I cannot find any answers anywhere outside of the Excel Vlookup function. I have not found a single example out there on the web of how to do this. The textbox is also formatted for a hyperlink.

```
Private Sub Combo4_AfterUpdate()
Dim CertNum As String
Dim VendorYN As String
CertNum = Me.Combo4.Value
If IsNull(VendorYN = DLookup("[VendorCert]", "[Calibration Data]", "[Certificate Number] = " & CertNum & "")) Then
        Me.Check10 = False
    Else
        Me.Check10 = True
        Me.Text12 = "Vendor Certificate Of Calibration#VendorYN#"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: See if this [link](http://allenbrowne.com/casu-09.html) helps.

Comment: @OverMind - Thanks for the link but the issue lies more within Dlookup. When I test to see what Dlookup returns by having a msgbox display VendorYN, it returns blank or Null. So I must be missing something in how I am formating my Dlookup. I've tried to put # in places within Dlookup but it doesn't like that either.

Comment: Try `"[Certificate Number] = " & CertNum`

Comment: @OverMind - It still is retuning empty after I changed it.

Comment: When you debug, what value does `CertNum` have after it has been assigned `Me.Combo4.Value` ?

Comment: @OverMind - for this particular instance it returns "132" which is correct. Also, the CertNum is the primary key auto-number for the table, if that information helps at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I used:

```
Dim CertNum As String
Dim VendorYN As String

CertNum = 132 'I hardcoded 132 to avoid building a combobox control

If IsNull(VendorYN = DLookup("[VendorCert]", "[Calibration Data]", "[Certificatio nNumber] = " & CertNum & "") = False Then

Me.TestText = VendorYN

Else

MsgBox "No Value"

End If
```

I also Formatted the properties of `Me.TestText`, on the `Data` tab, `Text Format`, `Rich Text`.

Comment: The CerNum will constantly change, it is based off of another combobox selection. Will that have any impact on how this functions?

Comment: That's fine. Your code should not change for the `CertNum` if it is giving you the correct values from `Combo4`

Comment: Ok, that worked and did return the correct hyperlink. I then set `Me.Text12` to display VendorYN and it did the same thing as before.

Comment: Did you do everything I said in my answer, regarding formatting the TextBox?

Comment: Yes, But I found out the issue there. I was using my original textbox. I deleted it and now it is displaying the hyperlink. Now when I set the properties to be a hyperlink, it shows the hand mouse pointer but when I click on it, it does nothing. Doesn't even show the security warning.

Comment: What if the hyperlink is a local or network drive? For this database it will be a link to a PDF stored on a network drive.

Comment: Also, if the dlookup returns empty, I get a "Invalid use of Null" error. So I tried to use the `If IsNull (...` then the whole code doesn't work.

Comment: If the hyperlink is a network drive, I'm not sure. I would probably run VBA with the file path from the textbox as a variable and use that in the code to open the pdf. As for evaluating the `IsNull` you need to add `= True` before your `Then`. It evaluates to  `TRUE or FALSE`.

Comment: I found out what works. `VendorYN = Nz(DLookup("[VendorCert]", "[Calibration Data]", "[Certificate Number] = " & CertNum & ""))` and then I continue on to my `if then` statement. That way I don't get the Null error message. Also, if I put `FollowHyperlink Me![TestText], , True` in the OnClick event for the textbox, it will open the file.

Comment: @Mgogan I'm glad you figured it out. Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: You can leave it if you wish. Someone else may be able to use the examples and discussion in the future.